# how to drag window elements

Tags: python, winapi, mouse, drag

I need to drag window border that divides main window into two parts.
I tried this:

```
import win32api
import win32con
win32api.SetCursorPos((700,1200))
win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN,700,1200,0,0)
win32api.SetCursorPos((700,960))
win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP,700,960,0,0)
```

and I also tried this:

```
import pywinauto
pywinauto.controls.HwndWrapper.DragMouse(button='left', pressed='', press_coords=(700,1200), release_coords=(700,960))
```

The first example does not work. It is just does not do anything.
The second one gives an error:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'DragMouse'
```

Did I imported it wrong?
Could someone give examples of dragging objects by mouse?

Leonid

Comment: could you further explain what it is that you need to be done? because from what i understand, your first example should work. which is *set cursor to position* --> *left mouse down* ---> *set new position* ---> *left mouse up*

Comment: @harristyle: Drag operations are usually implemented in a way that responds to mouse **move** messages. The naive implementation thus cannot be made to work. At any rate, the correct way to go about this is usually [UI Automation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee684009.aspx).

Comment: You use `DragMouse` from `pywinauto` incorrectly. Take a look at [the correct example](https://gist.github.com/vasily-v-ryabov/f6c6f4d94fe313be8236).

Answer (score 0):

I faced this problem too; after many searches, the solution for this problem is to use the `MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE` function.

For your example:

```
sx,sy=(win32api.GetCursorPos()) # get current mouse pos
win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE,700-sx,1200-sy,0,0) # use the MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE but send the deffrice betwwen current position and  first position

win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN,700,1200,0,0)# press left clik (send the first postion)

sx,sy=(win32api.GetCursorPos())  # get current mouse pos
win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE,700-sx,960-sy,0,0)  # use the MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE but send the deffrice betwwen current position and end position

win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP,700,960,0,0) # relase the left click (send the second postion)
```